# Avoid 'Proxy Authentication Required' in all my c# application

Tags: c#, authentication, proxy

In my application i use external resources on web that require proxy authentication.
All my requests are http type by using WebRequest / DataSet.ReadXml(url) / ecc.....
Every time i need to give credentials...

So is possible to assign credential only one time in my application?

Answer (score 1):

```
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

You can [set a defaultProxy element in your config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903360(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: If the proxy only allows request that called by the Browsers you must add user-agent string to your Request For exp: request.UserAgent="Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101"; If not It will return Error 403 - Forbidden